# Elementary reflector $Q$ is orthogonal iff

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

> Recall that an elementary reflector has the form $Q = I + \alpha xx^T\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with $\|x\|_{2}\neq 0$. Show that $Q$ is orthogonal iff $$\alpha = \frac{-2}{x^Tx} \ \ \text{or} \ \ \alpha = 0$$

Attempted solution - Suppose $Q = I + \alpha xx^T$ is orthogonal. Then \begin{align*}
Q^T Q = I \Rightarrow (I+\alpha xx^T)^T(I + \alpha xx^T) &= I + 2\alpha xx^T + \alpha^2 xx^T xx^T\\
&= I + xx^T(2\alpha + \alpha^2 xx^T) = I\\
\alpha &= \frac{-2}{xx^T}  \ \ \text{or} \ \ \alpha = 0
\end{align*}

I am not sure how I show the converse, any suggestions is greatly appreciated

Comment: http://www.math.fsu.edu/~gallivan/courses/FCM2new/hw3.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have shown everything you need (apart from the mistake you have made). Any elementary reflector $Q$ of the form above is symmetric and satisfies
\begin{align}
Q^T Q &= (I + \alpha xx^T)(I + \alpha xx^T) \\
&= I + 2\alpha xx^T + \alpha^2 (xx^T)(xx^T) \\
&= I + 2\alpha xx^T + \alpha^2 x(x^Tx)x^T \\
&= I + 2\alpha xx^T + \alpha^2 \|x\|^2_2 xx^T \\
&= I + \alpha xx^T(2+\alpha \|x\|_2^2),
\end{align}
so $Q$ is orthogonal iff $\alpha = 0$ or $\alpha = -2/\|x\|_2^2$.

Edit: The factorisation you made in the second line is not valid since $2\alpha$ is scalar whereas $\alpha^2xx^T$ is a matrix.